# Password change when the user login first time

Tags: redirect, login, password, wp-redirect

I have a "change password" page.

Is there a way to redirect that page when the user `login first time` using wordpress generated password?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps you?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267285/redirect-user-after-first-login-in-wordpress

He seems to had a similar problem and solved it a year ago.

What he does different to your approach is redirecting 48hrs after registration. 
Maybe this is enough?

If not - I'm looking to do it your way.

--- EDIT

Okay I just made a plugin what does exactly what you want:

```
/*
 Plugin Name: Redirect Passwort
Plugin URI: TODO
Description: TODO
Author: xaeDes
Version: 0.1
Author URI: TODO
License: GPL2
*/

function redirect_passwort_profile_update($user_id, $old_user_data) {
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    if( $user->data->user_pass != $old_user_data->user_pass) {
        //password has changed
        update_metadata("user",$user_id,"changed_password",true);
    }
}
add_action("profile_update", "redirect_passwort_profile_update", 10, 2);

function redirect_passwort_login_redirect($redirect_to, $url_redirect_to = '', $user = null) {

    if( isset($user->ID) ) {
        $changed_password = get_metadata("user", $user->ID, "changed_password",true);
        if( $changed_password != true ) {
            return get_bloginfo('url') . "/change-your-password-dude/";
        } else {
            return $redirect_to;
        }
    }
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_passwort_login_redirect',10,3);

function redirect_passwort_password_reset( $user ) {
    //password has been reset to a random one. so the changed_password meta data should be reset as well
    if( isset($user->ID) ) {
        delete_metadata("user", $user->ID, "changed_password");
    }
}
add_action('password_reset', 'redirect_passwort_password_reset');
```

It adds a user meta data "changed_password" to the user who changed its passwort.

When logging in it checks whether the user meta data "changed_password" is set and redirects if it is not set (and therefore the user has not changed its passwort even once).

When the users password is reset to a random one, the user meta data "changed_password" is reset as well.

Comment: I don't think its a good idea redirecting users to 
"change password" page based on 48hours time. It will be problem if the user login defferent times in those 48 hours. I don't want to redirect that user to change password page often.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the code. I tested your code. But its not working in my site. I'm using custom page for login. Is that the reason why its not working? Here is my [login function](http://pastebin.com/r45j4q0y). Do i have to modify any codes there?  Thanks

Comment: You have to change the url of the site you are redirecting to in my plugin:
`return get_bloginfo('url') . "/change-your-password-dude/";`

You are using wp_redirect to redirect to a site. But my plugin hooks into login_redirect, which is called from standard wordpress login. You could apply the login_redirect for yourself :  `wp_redirect(apply_filters('login_redirect',  get_bloginfo('url') . '/my-account/','', $user););` in your pastebin line 19.


Does that solve your problems?

Comment: No it doesn't. Here is my [modified login function](http://pastebin.com/8BU0qZfV). I created a new user and tested it. Its supposed to redirect to `change-password` page. But it still redirect to `my-account` page. And yes i replaced your `change-your-password-dude` text with my `change-password` text. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Which wordpress version are you using?

Could you check whether `redirect_passwort_profile_update` or `redirect_passwort_login_redirect` are ever called? Maybe add something like this as first line of the files :
`file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/log-'.__FUNCTION__.'_'.__LINE__, '');` and check the folder of the plugin for generated files.
The folder of the plugin have to be writable for the webserver.

Comment: I'm using wordpress 3.3.1. I copied your code and pasted in my functions.php file. I hope thats not the problem. you want me to add that file_put_contents in the top my functions.php file?

Comment: oh sorry, i made a mistake. i meant the first line of the functions i want you to check. the log files should appear in the folder of your functions.php file. by the way, what file is that? the functions.php from your theme? it may be, that the hooks are registered too late when called from the theme.

Comment: I created a new plugin with your code. And i erased the old codes in my theme function.php But still it redirect me to my-account page. I still not sure how to check that log file. But let me give it a try.

Comment: I added this line `file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/log-'.__FUNCTION__.'_'.__LINE__, '');` in the top of the plugin. I logged out and logged in again. Error log is not working. I mean i see this file in the plugin directory. `log-_11`. There is nothing inside that file.. By the way did you tested that plugin in your site.? If its working in your site then perhaps the problem might be caused by some other plugin.

Comment: It is working on my local machine. Put the line as the first line of the functions please to see whether the functions are called:
`function redirect_passwort_login_redirect($redirect_to, $url_redirect_to = '', $user = null) { 
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/log-'.__FUNCTION__.'_'.__LINE__, '');`
Its okay, that the file is empty. The code only creates an empty file with a specific name to see whether the code is ever called.

Comment: sorry bro, For wasting your time. The problem was caused by s2member plugin. I think i should remove previous filter/action hook to make it work. [This is the s2member file](http://pastebin.com/ZTkh0zxy) which is responsible for login redirects. Can you tell me what code i should use to remove s2member login redirect. Very much thanks

Comment: when changing the users password is a file named like 'log-redirect_passwort_profile_update_..' created?

If so, it would maybe better for you to simple let the system redirect to your s2member Login Welcome Page and output a hint to change their password, when they did not do it. This would be much easier than rummaging through the s2member source code. You could also add a simple javascript redirect to another side. Would this be ok?

Comment: Yes i see those log files.  Your plugin working when i disable s2member. The point is i'm preparing a series of page to update user profile on first time login. Its like this.. step 1: Change password step 2: upload avatar step 3: change  username (Allowed only once) step 4: Update profile fields. Thats why i prefer your plugin than displaying hints. Let me open a support thread in s2member community. Very much thanks for all your efforts.  If you can please answer [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46782/one-time-username-change-from-frontend) too

Answer (score 2):

Hook [user_register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) and [add user metadata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) to store a "has not logged in yet" flag. Hook [wp_login](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) and check for that metadata, delete and redirect if it exists, otherwise do normal login behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Milo's answer:

```
    function after_user_register( $user_id ){

        // the new user just registered but never logged in yet
        add_user_meta($user_id, "has_not_logged_in_yet", "true", true);
    }

    add_action( 'user_register', 'after_user_register', 10, 1 );

    function after_user_loggedin(){

        if(is_user_logged_in()){

            $user_id=get_current_user_id();

            $user_meta=get_user_meta($user_id);

            if(isset($user_meta['has_not_logged_in_yet'])){

                delete_user_meta($user_id, "has_not_logged_in_yet");

                //do something else
            }
        }
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'after_user_loggedin');
```

**Edit (FYI)**

Hook `wp_login` is not performing very well in terms of user meta retrieval. Sometimes returns `FALSE` with the user loggedin.