# One time username change from frontend?

Tags: plugin-development, privileges, username

I'm using facebook connect plugin.

Usernames generated by that plugin look like firstname_lastname. I mean it looks ugly.

I would like to give the privilege to my users to change the username **BUT ONCE**.

I hope its like changing the password.

Here is my [change password function](http://pastebin.com/bxMPzRqk).

Can anyone help me to modify it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a meta record that tracks the state of the username-changing actions:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();

$did_one_change = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'changed_username', true);

if($did_one_change !== false)
  wp_die('You already changed your user name once!');

wp_update_user(array(
  'ID'         => $user->ID, 
  'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
  'last_name'  => $_POST['last_name'],
));

// here add a meta entry that suggests the user has changed their name once
update_user_meta($user->ID, 'changed_username', 1);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer , but what will happen if username already exists?

Comment: you can check that before doing the update: [`username_exists()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/username_exists)